# CSS3 linear-gradient not working on android.

Tags: android, css

Newbie question here but for some reason I cant figure this out. I have the following CSS which works fine on my iPhone but not an my Android. From looking at the jQuery Mobile demos with the android I know it can handle background gradients. Thanks

```
.mydiv {
  background:    -moz-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #F1F1F1) repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEEE;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #F1F1F1) repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEEE;
  background: linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #F1F1F1) repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEEE;
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Android browser below 4.0, according to **[caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=gradient,)** uses the old `-webkit` syntax:

```
background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #a7cfdf), color-stop(100%, #23538a));
```

Bonus: I recommend you use something like LESS or Compass/SASS, it would save you all this work http://compass-style.org/

Comment: What is it for android 2.2? Every variation ive tried doenst work. Thanks

Comment: What variations have you tried? Have you tried this one  "background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #000000), color-stop(100%, #ffffff));" ?

Comment: I tested it myself and only the old syntax works. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Note, you can use background or background-image.

Comment: note that you can have more then two gradient points added by adding more color-stops, something like: "background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #a7cfdf), color-stop(40%, #23538a), color-stop(100%, #a7cfdf));".

Answer (score 3):

I came across this question because I was having issues with linear gradients on an Android 2.2. The issue was, our linear gradient was using the new angle system

```
-webkit-linear-gradient(to top #000000 0%, #ffffff 100%)
```

however, older Android's support the old angle system (without *to*). The equivalent of the above gradient would be

```
-webkit-linear-gradient(bottom #000000 0%, #ffffff 100%)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
background-color:#666633; //fallback
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #666633,    #333300);  //webkit
background:-moz-linear- gradient(top, #666633, #333300) //mozilla
```

This works.

Comment: Im getting a solid colour but according to this site http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-linear-gradient-syntax/ "Mobile support for linear gradients includes: iOS 3.2+, Opera Mini 5+, Opera Mobile 10+, and Android Browser 2.1+." and my android is 2.2 so it should work.

Comment: That is strange.  Works on my GNex with 4.0.  It's really tough to keep up with CSS3 syntax these days.

Comment: Maybe the jQuery Mobile demos are using background images, but without any firebug type thing its hard to know.

Comment: Try using background-image: instead of background. Other than that, I don't have a any way to test how exactly Android 2.2 handles gradients so I can only guess.