# Linear-Gradient not working on Android device (NativeScript 8)

Tags: android, css, angular, nativescript

I implemented a linear-gradient to an image in my NativeScript 8 app. it works fine on iOS but Android somehow has some issues with it. I also tried solutions like using `-webkit-linear-gradient()` but it still doesn't do what I expect it to do.

here is my implementation:

HTML

```
  <GridLayout rows="auto, auto, auto, auto, auto">
    <image class="backgroundImage" src="~/assets/images/registration.png"></image>
    ...
    ...
    ...
  </GridLayout>
```

and my CSS

```
.backgroundImage {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 85%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 85%);
  width: 100%;
}
```

Screenshot on my iOS emulator (that's how it should look)

[image: Screenshot on my iOS emulator (that's how it should look)]

Screenshot of my Android Emulator (Gradient not working here)

[image: Screenshot of my Android Emulator (Gradient not working here)]

my question: what is wrong with my implementation and what is causing this behaviour on Android?

Comment: Take a look at the most recent answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536876/css3-linear-gradient-not-working-on-android I know the answer is old but it could still be relevant. You could also try using `background-image` instead of `background` https://v7.docs.nativescript.org/ui/components/styling#gradients

Have you tried viewing it on an actual device and not an emulator? Emulators seem to give mixed results. Try viewing it on a few different devices on  https://www.browserstack.com/

Comment: Hello AStombaugh, 

I already tried to view it on my physical Android device but no change and yes I also tried using background-image already as given in the most recent answer question (I tried the answers in that questions first before creating this new question). There is no change unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overlay the image (or any component) with a gradient layer to achieve similar results on the both platforms.

**Template**

```
  <GridLayout rows="auto, auto, auto, auto, auto">
    <Image row="0" src="~/assets/images/registration.png"/>
    <ContentView row="0" height="100%" class="my-gradient"/>
    ... Other Components
  </GridLayout>
```

**Style**

```
  .my-gradient {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1))
  }
```